# Derivative of $\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}$ is bounded in $[0,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, upper-lower-bounds

Given the function $g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}\right)$, I want to prove it is bounded in $[0,\pi]$.

For me, it is immediate that it is bounded in $(0,\pi]$, as $\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}$ is continuous in $(0,\pi]$. Please, correct me if this needs to be proved with more detail.

Then, how I prove it is bounded in 0? Is it useful to compute the limit of $\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}$ in $0$?. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In general you cannot infer that from the continuity of $f$ in some interval $(a,b)$, the derivative $f'$ has to be bounded in $(a, b)$. For instance consider $f(x)  = \sqrt x$ in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Another example is $\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x)=f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{x}{4}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$
Simplify
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-x\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}= \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-x\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{4\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\le\frac{1}{2}$$
From the graph below

---

[image]

Comment: Is it obvious $2\sin\tfrac{x}{2}-x\cos\tfrac{x}{2}\le2\sin^2\tfrac{x}{2}$?

Comment: @J.G. Why is it obvious? Maybe because $x \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\geq 2-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

Comment: That's just a rearrangement. Do you know a proof of that inequality for $x\in[0,\,\pi]$?

Comment: @J.G. The $x$ in front of cosine made me choose the graphic way. Taylor expansion is not effective in inequalities. If you know how to prove, please let me know!